# RStudio does not launch after installation

Tags: xubuntu

I am running Xubuntu. I have been using RStudio without problems. However I remove RStudio and install again. The problem is that I cannot launch RStudio after the new installation. The buttom of RStudio appears but when I click on it the program does not open. Any way to solve it ? I am desperate

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is **THE** solution (and it's probably too late?) but it might be good to check the following fix I used for a similar issue on my Kubuntu 14.04 (the same happened with 15.10) where I couldn't launch RStudio neither from launcher nor from terminal.
If you have warning messages when starting R about language configuration (sorry I don't remember exactly what was the message as I solved it...) it might be the cause of non-starting RStudio.
The same problem of locale settings is visible when you use apt-get and you get "LC_ALL = (unset)".
I got it fixed very easily thanks to [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1720356) where it's explained how to edit the file *environment*. Using:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

you add a line:

```
LC_ALL="en_GB.utf8"
```

and then reboot

(adapt "en_GB.utf8" with the language you want).

After a reboot RStudio could be launched from command line as well as KDE launcher.
... it just took me 48h to find it out :-/

Comment: Please include the essential part of the linked resource in case it changes or becomes unavailable.

Comment: didn't work for me. I think I need to invest my part of 48h. :)