# Rstudio in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, rstudio

i installed Rstudio in Ubuntu 19.04, the installation had no problems but the software does not open, any solution?

Comment: related to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/675223/rstudio-does-not-launch-after-installation/1213490#1213490

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any trouble installing RStudio on 19.04 just a few days ago. I downloaded the .deb from https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download and installed it using the following commands.

```
sudo apt install gdebi-core
sudo gdebi rstudio-1.2.1335-amd64.deb
```

I elected to use this route based on instructions from https://linuxconfig.org/rstudio-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux and reading the notes on https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-does-not-install-on-debian-10-or-ubuntu-19-04-depends-on-old-libssl/24883. Unfortunately, I can't find the link that lead me to the exact commands I used above.

Comment: If this doesn't help, can you please give some more information on how you installed the software and what you have tried to do? Also, you might try running it from the command line to see if you get any useful error messages.  -- A note to editors, I don't have commenting privileges yet or I would have simply commented this on the question.

Comment: You don't need gdebi to install a .deb file. Double clicking it opens the software installer, click install, done. Or using dpkg in terminal.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that gdebi wasn't needed. At any rate, this is what I did to install and it is working for me. I wonder if gdebi might have installed it differently. I'll remove the answer if a better one comes along.

Comment: Gdebi does the same as the default Ubuntu Software. It does nothing different than the default. Both call dpkg and then install it if all dependencies are satisfied or if not give an error message.

Comment: I've made a script that installs Rstudio on 18.04,18.10, and 19.04, including many much used libraries in data science: https://gist.github.com/ElToro1966/999f1c8ca51a75648dd587a3170e4335

Answer (score 1):

You have to download correct version of RStudio from their site - https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/ :

> [RStudio 1.2.1335 - Ubuntu 18/Debian 10 (64-bit)](https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.2.1335-amd64.deb)

and install it by

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.2.1335-amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-1.2.1335-amd64.deb
```

then it will work as expected on Ubuntu 19.04 and will not have problems with SSL library:

> ```
> $ ldd $(which rstudio) | grep ssl
> libssl.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f3c2d73e000)
> ```

Note: I have just tested this on clean Ubuntu 19.04 VM and even on Ubuntu 19.10 (latest development version) VM.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution, i hope that help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929757/installing-r-3-6-on-ubuntu-disco-19-04

The following steps are shown in the link.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base-dev
```

you can see the instructions to install R 3.6 packages in Disco Dingo (19.04)

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html

I hope and this can be of help.

Comment: Hello and welcome on Ask Ubuntu :) Link-only answers are discouraged as they might become irrelevant if the linked site changes. May I suggest you to summarize the steps to follow in your answer?

Answer (score -1):

I tried several ways of downloading rstudio on my new laptop which runs ubuntu 19 but no luck. I think Rstudio need to release a new version to run on ubuntu 19.
For the time being I'm using rstudio server, which you can download on ubunutu 19 - https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/

Comment: You have to choose latest available version of RStudio.

Answer (score -1):

Download libssl1.0.0 for an older version and install it manually. They will eventually update their required version of libssl (probably for the next LTS)

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.10/ubuntu-main-amd64/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb.html

In general, a good way to investigate why a program isn't opening in desktop linux is to open a terminal and type the command. In my case:

```
beb@os: $ rstudio
rstudio: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open 
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Told me that libssl.so.1.0.0 was mising.

Comment: It is a bad idea. LibSSL is essential part of system security, you should not downgrade it.